Creating an array of SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE in PLSQL procedure
I want to be able to enqueue an array of SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE into a queue using the dbms_aq.enqueue_array. Can someone tell me how I can create the payload array which will be an array of AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE. I'm getting an error when adding the message text to the nested table.
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE (
    queue_name => 'demo_aq_array_q'
    );
  DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE (
     queue_name => 'demo_aq_array_q'
     );
  DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE_TABLE (
     queue_table => 'demo_aq_array_qt'
     );
END;
/

DROP TYPE demo_aq_array_ntt
/

DROP TYPE demo_aq_array_ot
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE demo_aq_array_ot AS OBJECT
  ( id      number(10),
    message sys.aq$_jms_text_message
  );
/

CREATE TYPE demo_aq_array_ntt
AS TABLE OF demo_aq_array_ot;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
     queue_table        => 'demo_aq_array_qt',
     queue_payload_type => 'demo_aq_array_ot'
     );
  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
     queue_name  => 'demo_aq_array_q',
     queue_table => 'demo_aq_array_qt'
     );
  DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (
    queue_name => 'demo_aq_array_q'
    );
END;
/

set serverout on size 1000000
DECLARE

   r_enqueue_options DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
   r_msg_properties  DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
   nt_msg_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY_T;
   nt_payloads       demo_aq_array_ntt;
   nt_msg_ids        DBMS_AQ.MSGID_ARRAY_T;
   v_enqueued_cnt    PLS_INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN

   /* Initialise the collections... */
   nt_payloads := demo_aq_array_ntt();
   nt_msg_properties := DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_ARRAY_T();
   nt_msg_ids := DBMS_AQ.MSGID_ARRAY_T();

   /* Load up 2500 arbitrary messages... */
   FOR i IN 1 .. 2500 LOOP

      nt_payloads.EXTEND;
      nt_payloads(nt_payloads.LAST).message := sys.aq$_jms_bytes_message.construct;
      /* nt_payloads(nt_payloads.LAST) := demo_aq_array_ot(
                                          i,
                                          self.set_text('Message number ' || TO_CHAR(i))
                                           ); */ -- This is where I am getting an error

      nt_msg_properties.EXTEND;
      nt_msg_properties(nt_msg_properties.LAST) := r_msg_properties;

   END LOOP;

   /* Enqueue the messages in a single transaction... */
   v_enqueued_cnt := DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_ARRAY(
                        queue_name               => 'demo_aq_array_q',
                        enqueue_options          => r_enqueue_options,
                        array_size               => nt_payloads.COUNT,
                        message_properties_array => nt_msg_properties,
                        payload_array            => nt_payloads,
                        msgid_array              => nt_msg_ids
                        );
   COMMIT;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      'Enqueued [' || TO_CHAR(v_enqueued_cnt) || '] messages.'
      );

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      'Received [' || TO_CHAR(nt_msg_ids.COUNT) || '] message IDs.'
      );

END;
/


Please share the error you are getting.

@Speeddymon
Error report - ORA-06550: line 21, column 74: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 21, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 24, column 43: PLS-00201: identifier 'SELF.SET_TEXT' must be declared ORA-06550: line 22, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
